# (possibly silly) question about the energy-momentum relation

Tags: momentum, mass-energy

On the wikipedia entry for the energy-momentum relation, it states that, for certain systems,
$$
E^2=(pc)^2+(m_0c^2)^2
$$
where $E$ is total energy, $p$ is momentum, $m_0$ is rest mass, and $c$ is the speed of light.  Now, supposedly $E$, $c$, and $m_0$ are all scalar quantities, but $p$ is a vector.  So, what does it mean to square the vector in the first term on the RHS?  Is that just an abuse of notation for the dot product?

Sorry if this is a silly question, but I have no physics background.

Comment: Instead of $p^2$ consider $\vec{p} \cdot \vec{p}$

Comment: "scalar" should not be used to mean "just a number" here (or ever, imho), i.e.  "Energy". It means something that is invariant under rotations (or Lorentz transformations). So energy is a 3-scalar (under spatial rotations), but it is *not* a Lorentz scalar (it depends on reference frame).

Comment: @JEB Hmm, I don't really understand that.  What is a 3-scalar?

Comment: There's no notation to suggest $p$ is a vector, momentum is a vector quantity, yes, which **should** be labelled as $\underline{p}$ or $\mathbf{p}$ or $\vec{p}$ if they were denoting the vector. In this case, they're denoting the magnitude of the momentum squared: $|\underline{p}|^2=p^2=\mathbf{p}\cdot \mathbf{p}$.

Comment: A 3-scalar doesn't change under a rotation. A 4-scalar (like $m=\sqrt{E^2-\vec p \cdot \vec p}$) doesn't change under a rotation or boosts, so a scalar is a geometric object, while a number is just a number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, $p^2 := p \cdot p := \sum_{i=1}^n p_i^2$ with $\cdot$ the scalar product as you correctly guessed, and $n$ the number of dimensions in Euclidean space. Note that there might be a [minus sign for the space components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_space#Scalar_product) in Minkowski space, which is the usual signature for special relativity.